# How to prove that the Riemann surface $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2: y^2=x(x^2-1)(x^2-4)\}$ admits a non-constant holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some idea about using the removable singularity theorem but have difficulty in carrying out the whole proof. Also, I'm interested in why this riemann surface cannot admit a bounded non-const holomorphic function.

Comment: Consider the function $(x,y) \longmapsto y$?

Comment: Can you not adapt an in class example (or a book example) to this case to see why both $x$ and $y$ are holomorphic? Anyway, I want to encourage you to take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). The shortcomings in your question make it difficult to give a helpful answer. When you tell us only little about what you know, it is impossible to help. We could guess, but rather not.